# Confusion about the shrinking Hubble volume

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-inflation

The particle horizon is given by
\begin{equation}
\chi_p(\eta) = 
\int_{t_i}^{t}\frac{dt}{a}
=
\int_{a_i}^{a}\frac{da}{a\dot{a}}
=
\int_{\ln a_i}^{\ln a} (aH)^{-1}\ d\ln a
.
\end{equation}

For a universe dominated by a fluid with constant equation of state $w = P/\rho$ we have,
\begin{equation}
(aH)^{-1} = H_0^{-1}a^{\frac{1}{2}(1 + 3w)}
.
\end{equation}

We can calculate the the particle horizon explicitly for this case,
\begin{equation}
\chi_p(a) = \frac{2H_0^{-1}}{(1 + 3w)}
\left[
a^{\frac{1}{2}(1 + 3w)} 
-
a_i^{\frac{1}{2}(1 + 3w)} 
\right]
\equiv
\eta - \eta_i
\end{equation}

For familiar matter sources ($1 + 3w > 0$) the largest contribution comes from later times, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\eta_i
=
\frac{2H_0^{-1}}{(1 + 3w)}a_i^{\frac{1}{2}(1 + 3w)}
\longrightarrow
0
\quad \text{for}\quad a_i\to 0,\ w > -\frac{1}{3}
.
\end{equation}

Therefore, the comoving horizon is finite
\begin{equation}
\chi_p(t) = 
\frac{2H_0^{-1}}{(1 + 3w)}a(t)^{\frac{1}{2}(1 + 3w)} = \frac{2}{(1 + 3w)}(aH)^{-1}
.
\end{equation}

Using this as motivation, [Baumann](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mvp7oe5qn5qrih6/Chapter2.pdf?dl=0) and Dodelson suggest that the natural solution to the [horizon problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem) is to conjecture a phase of *decreasing Hubble radius* in the early universe,

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(aH)^{-1} < 0.
$$

This is cited as the solution because the Hubble sphere is *growing* in standard Big Bang cosmology.

Now, I don't understand why it is a *natural* or *easy* solution to consider a period of time where the Hubble radius is decreasing. Is there some key insight that I am missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the motivation for *inflation*, which is defined as expansion where the scale factor satisfies $\ddot{a} > 0$.  During inflation, the Hubble scale as measured with respect to the expansion (so-called comoving coordinates) is shrinking because the expansion proceeds at a greater rate than the proper Hubble distance.

A cosmological fluid with $p < -\rho/3$, like vacuum energy or scalar quantum fields with most of their energy stored as potential energy, are suitable sources of inflationary expansion.